# Datatables align row full width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have set up a bootstrap datatable but my search and my pagination inputs are not pulled to the right as usual. You can see this here:

[image]

Can you guys tell me why and how this error is caused and how I can fix it?

This is my table:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="client_overview_table_div" class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="client_overview_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="text-center"></th>
    <th class="text-center"></th>
    ...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>..</td>
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `table-responsive` over-riding the datatables default css?

Comment: No... I have simply added my own css and set the row to 100% - Working now!